What is the difference between the two lights
In genesis 1:3-5 God Created light And also In genesis 1:14-19 God created light once again What is the differences between These two lights

In 1 John 1:5 we read:

And this is the message we have heard from Him and announce to you:
God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all.

Since God is eternal, I am not sure that Gen 1:3 can be construed as suggesting that God created light on the first day of creation week for two reasons:

light must have surrounded God as long as God existed, which predated the earth
In simply physical terms, the fact that we can see stars that are many hundreds of millions of light-years away suggests that light existed long before the earth was created.

therefore, in Gen 1:3-5, the primary function was the separation of light from darkness to created day vs night.  Indeed, God's only function on the first three days of creation was separation as follows:

Day #1 - separation of light from darkness
Day #2 - separation of water above from water below to create the sky
Day #3 - separation of dry ground from seas to create arable land

On days 4-6, these new separated environments be then populated in the same order:

Day #4 - sky populated with two great lights [Note: the text goes to some trouble to avoid the perfectly good Hebrew words for "Sun" and "Moon", suggesting that God did not create these bodies on day 4 but simply allowed their light to appear then.]
Day #5 - sea and sky populated with sea creatures and sky populated with birds
Day #6 - land populated with animals and mankind

